# SASS: all css after @include a mixin is ignored

Tags: sass, include, mixins

Is something wrong with this code?

```
@mixin background2x($path, $ext: "png", $w: auto, $h: auto, $pos: left top, $repeat: no-repeat) {

      $at1x_path: "#{$path}.#{$ext}";
      $at2x_path: "#{$path}@2x.#{$ext}";

      background-image: url("#{$at1x_path}");
      background-size: $w $h;
      background-position: $pos;
      background-repeat: $repeat;

      @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
      all and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
      all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
      all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        background-image: url("#{$at2x_path}"); 
      }
    }



    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
          .navbar-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
             @include background2x("../images/navigation/menu-button-expanded",png,60px, 60px,left,no-repeat);
          }
          body {
             background:#ff0000;
          }
       }
```

all `css` after the include, in the above code the **body** statement, is being ignored by the parsers

*I revised above code because I accidently added an extra `}`, but that  was not the problem*

The problem is that the mixin itself works as expected, but that my sass compiler (scout-app) gives me 
**WRONG**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle[aria-expanded=true] {
    background-image: url("../images/navigation/menu-button-expanded.png");
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

}
```

while I expect to get
**GOOD**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle[aria-expanded=true] {
    background-image: url("../images/navigation/menu-button-expanded.png");
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  body {
    background: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to figure out if the problem is with my formatting (which seems to be ok), or with the scout-app

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your mixin before you call it. Also, there was a `}` too much after the `body` element.
this should work:

```
@mixin background2x($path, $ext: "png", $w: auto, $h: auto, $pos: left top, $repeat: no-repeat) {

  $at1x_path: "#{$path}.#{$ext}";
  $at2x_path: "#{$path}@2x.#{$ext}";

  background-image: url("#{$at1x_path}");
  background-size: $w $h;
  background-position: $pos;
  background-repeat: $repeat;

  @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
  all and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
  all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    background-image: url("#{$at2x_path}"); 
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
   .navbar-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
     @include background2x("../images/navigation/menu-button-expanded",png,60px, 60px,left,no-repeat);
    }
    body {
       background:#ff0000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Christophe thanx: i revised the code in my question, because I was not clear enough, and making typos is presenting a wrong problem so wasting your time, sorry about that